# how to filter array with multiple properties in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular6

I have created a pipe in my angular 5 project, which will takes the input from html and filter array and will return filtered array. But currently I am passing the property name("firstName") from HTML file. Now i want that, it should filter from properties "firstName" and "lastName" both. Please tell me what should i change to do the same ???

> search-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: any, search?: string, propertyName?: string): any {
        if (search === undefined) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return data.filter(obj => obj[propertyName].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
        }
    }
}
```

> user.component.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of datas| searchFilter: search: 'firstName'}">
   {{data.lastName}}, {{data.firstName}}
</div>
```

> sample-data.ts

```
 datas: [
{ firstName: 'vipin', company: 'abc', lastName: 'sharma' },
{ firstName: 'kevin', company: 'abc2', lastName: 'xyz' },
{ firstName: 'Leos', company: 'abc3', lastName: 'abc' },
]
```

Comment: Pass search text like 'firstName|lastName' & split that in pipe then search appropriate

Comment: Could you please write the code of directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer and its working fine :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: any, search?: string, propertyName?: string, propertyName2?: string): any {
        if (search === undefined) {
            return data;
        } else {
            let filteredData = data.filter(obj => obj[propertyName].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
            if (propertyName2) {
                filteredData = filteredData.concat(data.filter(obj => obj[propertyName2].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())));
            }
            return filteredData;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is concat the properties you want to search on:

```
this.items.map((item) => {
  return {...item, searchTerms: item.firstname + item.lastname;
});

<li *ngFor="let item of items | searchFilter:search:'searchTerms'>{{item.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
 this.data.filter((element: datatype) =>element.firstName && element.lastName)
```